# Why doesn't opacity value work for Gradient Map in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, photo-editing

I've noticed it many times. When you apply a gradient map in Photoshop to any image or layer, the opacity doesn't work for any points (highlighted in yellow).

Basically, I want one color to be 100% opaque, and other should be 100% transparent, so it doesn't affect *unwanted areas* of my image.

But when I tried to move the opacity slider or bring down the value to 0%, it didn't show any change. Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: A gradient map doesn't support transparency. If you want to apply a gradient map selectively, you'd need to make a selection first so that the gradient map is only applied to the selected areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe doesn't give excuses. It's not implemented and that's that. A marketing person  could say "Our software is designed for highest quality, best performance and to meet customer's needs with pinpoint accuracy. Wish you well and happy new year!".

You can insert a layer mask to make the transparency as an extra step. Make a gradient map where the stops are in the same places, but the colors are black and white.

Here's another fightaround: [Photoshop, gradient map to transparent?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57528/photoshop-gradient-map-to-transparent)

Comment: Well. *Adobe doesn't give excuses.* What do you mean by this?

Comment: In their support  Adobe can tell does something exist or not if one asks, but they do not explain why a program hasn't still got this or that.